# Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (19,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have seen many examples with similar title `Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (19,) but got array with shape (1,)` in stackoverflow. I  still couldn't figure out issue. Below is the complete summary of my model.

### Problem Description

I am working on a classification problem. The dataset was collected from the competition hosted by kaggle, **Painters by number**. The task is to identify painter,style and genre given paintings.So far, I trained individual models to predict painter,style,genre given paintings. Now i would like to incorporate Multi task learning (i.e) developing a single model which can predict all three tasks. I came up with the  architecture specified by 
[Multi Task Learning Architecture](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/is-it-possible-to-pass-multiple-data-generators-for-multiple-inputs-to-model-fit)

```
input_layer   = Input(shape=(224,224,3))

shared_conv = Convolution2D(
            filters = 5,# 5 feature maps
            kernel_size = (5,5),
            strides = 1) 

shared_conv_layer_A = shared_conv(input_layer)

relu_shared = Activation('relu')(shared_conv_layer_A)

pooling = MaxPooling2D(
        pool_size = (2,2),
        strides = 2
      )(relu_shared)

dense_layer_flatten = Flatten()(pooling)
denselayer1 = Dense(100)(dense_layer_flatten)
denselayer2 = Dense(100)(denselayer1)

out_style_1 = Dense(
        100, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation='relu'
    )(denselayer2)

out_genre_1 = Dense(
        100, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation='relu'
    )(denselayer2)

out_painter_1 = Dense(
        100, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation='relu'
    )(denselayer2)

out_style_2 = Dense(
        19, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(out_style_1)

out_genre_2 = Dense(
        32, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(out_genre_1)

out_painter_2 = Dense(
        10, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(out_painter_1)

multi_tasking_model = Model(inputs=[input_layer],outputs=[out_style_2,out_genre_2,out_painter_2])
multi_tasking_model.summary()


multi_tasking_model.compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
  optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.00000001),metrics=['accuracy'] )


history = multi_tasking_model.fit_generator(
   generator = train_generator,
   steps_per_epoch= 2920//10,
   validation_data = valid_generator,
   validation_steps = 690//10
)
```

### Data Provider

Using keras data provider for this task was not helpful. So I have created a custom data provider. Reference([Stanford data provider](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html))

```
import numpy as np

class DataGenerator(object):

  def __init__(self,dim_x = 64,dim_y=32,dim_z=32,batch_size=32,
shuffle=True,data=None,style=None,genre=None,painter=None):

    self.dim_x = dim_x
    self.dim_y = dim_y
    self.dim_z = dim_z
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.shuffle=shuffle
    self.data = data
    self.y_style = style
    self.y_genre = genre
    self.y_painter = painter

 @property
 def data(self):
    return self._data

 @data.setter
 def data(self,value):
    self._data = value

 @property
 def y_style(self):
    return self._y_style

 @y_style.setter
 def y_style(self,value):
    self._y_style=value

 @property
 def y_genre(self):
    return self._y_genre

 @y_genre.setter
 def y_genre(self,value):
    self._y_genre = value

 @property
 def y_painter(self):
    return self._y_painter

 @y_painter.setter
 def y_painter(self,value):
    self._y_painter = value

 def __get_exploration_order(self,len_list_ids):
    indexes = np.arange(len_list_ids)
    if self.shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(indexes)
    return indexes

 def __data_generation(self,list_ids_temp):
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size,self.dim_x,self.dim_y,self.dim_z))
    y_style = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
    y_genre = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
    y_painter = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    for i, ID in enumerate(list_ids_temp):
        X[i,:,:,:] = self.data[ID]

        y_style = self.y_style[ID]
        y_genre = self.y_genre[ID]
        y_painter = self.y_painter[ID]

    return X,[y_style,y_genre,y_painter]


 def generate(self,len_list_ids):
    while 1:
        indexes = self.__get_exploration_order(len_list_ids)

        imax = int(len(indexes)/self.batch_size)
        for i in range(imax):
            list_ids_temp = [ k for k in indexes[i*self.batch_size:(i+1)*self.batch_size]]

            X,y = self.__data_generation(list_ids_temp)

            yield X,y
```

### Data Provider Initialization

```
  from DataGenerator import DataGenerator

  params = {
  'dim_x': 224,
  'dim_y': 224,
  'dim_z': 3,
  'batch_size':10,
  'shuffle':True
 }

 data_train_gen = DataGenerator(**params)
 data_train_gen.data = np.load('data.npy')
 data_train_gen.y_style = np.load('y_style.npy')
 data_train_gen.y_genre = np.load('y_genre.npy')
 data_train_gen.y_painter = np.load('y_painter.npy')
 train_generator=data_train_gen.generate(data_train_gen.data.shape[0])


 data_gen_valid = DataGenerator(**params)
 data_gen_valid.data = np.load('data_valid.npy')
 data_gen_valid.y_style = np.load('y_style_valid.npy')
 data_gen_valid.y_genre = np.load('y_genre_valid.npy')
 data_gen_valid.y_painter = np.load('y_painter_valid.npy')
 valid_generator= data_gen_valid.generate(data_gen_valid.data.shape[0])
```

### Model Summary

```
   Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
   input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)    0
   conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 220, 220, 5)  380         input_1[0][0]
   activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 220, 220, 5)    0         conv2d_1[0][0]
   max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 110, 110, 5)    0         activation_1[0][0]
   flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 60500)          0         max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
   dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 100)      6050100         flatten_1[0][0]
   dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          10100       dense_1[0][0]
   dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          10100       dense_2[0][0]
   dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          10100       dense_2[0][0]
   dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          10100       dense_2[0][0]
   dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 19)           1919        dense_3[0][0]
   dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           3232        dense_4[0][0]
   dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 10)           1010        dense_5[0][0]
```

### Data Description

```
   Data(train)                shape
   --------------            --------        
   data_train.npy            (2920,224,244,3)       
   y_style_train.npy         (2920, 19)
   y_genre_train.npy         (2920, 32)
   y_painter_train.npy       (2920,10)

   Data(valid)                shape
   --------------            --------        
   data_valid.npy            (690,224,244,3)       
   y_style_valid.npy         (690, 19) -- made change as per @JamesDong from 16 to 19
   y_genre_valid.npy         (690, 32) -- made change as per @JamesDong from 23 to 32
   y_painter_valid.npy       (690,10)
```

### Sample output from generator

```
 (array([[[[112., 129., 121.],
     [133., 150., 144.],
     [112., 130., 132.],
     ...,
     [ 23.,  22.,  20.],
     [ 21.,  20.,  18.],
     [ 20.,  19.,  17.]],

    [[109., 126., 118.],
     [125., 141., 138.],
     [109., 124., 127.],
     ...,
     [ 24.,  23.,  21.],
     [ 21.,  20.,  18.],
     [ 18.,  17.,  15.]],

    [[101., 116., 111.],
     [109., 125., 122.],
     [ 97., 112., 115.],
     ...,
     [ 26.,  25.,  23.],
     [ 21.,  20.,  18.],
     [ 17.,  16.,  14.]],

    ...,

    [[ 27.,  30.,  19.],
     [ 27.,  30.,  19.],
     [ 25.,  28.,  17.],
     ...,
     [ 48.,  48.,  24.],
     [ 47.,  47.,  21.],
     [ 46.,  46.,  18.]],

    [[ 27.,  30.,  19.],
     [ 28.,  31.,  20.],
     [ 24.,  27.,  16.],
     ...,
     [ 51.,  51.,  27.],
     [ 55.,  55.,  29.],
     [ 54.,  54.,  26.]],

    [[ 30.,  33.,  22.],
     [ 31.,  34.,  23.],
     [ 27.,  30.,  19.],
     ...,
     [ 62.,  62.,  38.],
     [ 87.,  87.,  61.],
     [104., 104.,  76.]]]]), (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
   0]), array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])))
```

I believe i have posted all the information that is available to me. I am completely stuck. Any suggestions would be greatly help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your data description, the shape of validation dataset is inconsistent.

```
y_style_valid.npy         (690, 16)
```

should be (690,19)

```
y_genre_valid.npy         (690, 23)
```

should be (690,32)

There are also some errors in function `__data_generation` as described below:

```
        #y_style,y_genre,y_painter should be initialized with shape (batch_size,19),(batch_size,32),(batch_size,10) instead of (batchsize).
        y_style = np.empty((self.batch_size,19), dtype=int) 
        y_genre = np.empty((self.batch_size,32), dtype=int)
        y_painter = np.empty((self.batch_size,10), dtype=int)

        ......
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_ids_temp):

            ....
            #And accordingly, the assignment should be changed as the following:
            y_style[i,:] = self.y_style[ID]
            y_genre[i,:] = self.y_genre[ID]
            y_painter[i,:] = self.y_painter[ID]
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking, Is that the reason for this cause of error ?. Should i need to make it consistent.?

Comment: @JamesJohnson The Shape of Validation data should be same as that of train data. The error :`Error when checking target` means either train or validation output data is  incrorrect.

Comment: I made it consistent, even then it says the same error

Comment: I had to reshape y_style,y_genre,y_painter. For instance i had to do this y_style.reshape(1,-1).  Just out of curiosity,      is                                   y_style[i,:] = self.y_style[ID] is equal to  y_style.reshape(1,-1) ?